# Safari language issues after Adware or Malware has been installed

Tags: macos, safari, language, safari-extensions

My mother has a MacBook Air, Early 2015, 1.6GHz Intel Core i5, running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 with Safari version 11.0.3.

My brother, whilst browsing through some shady streaming websites ended up installing the "Mac CleanUp Pro" app, which, from what I've found, is actually quite infamous. I think I managed to uninstall it (not so sure, if you have any advice on that too, it would be great)  but some problems remained. There are two Safari plug-ins which piggybacked their way in with the cleaner. Here's a screenshot of them.

[image: Here's the first one]

[image: And here's the second one]

The most annoying side effect which of all this is that the language of the  browser remains English, regardless of the system language I am using. And this, for the not so excellent English speaker who is my mother, is an issue. Also, as you can see, there's no uninstall option whatsoever.

I did a fair amount of research and I can say that I've literally tried whatever could be tried by someone not so tech-savvy such as myself:

- I removed any suspicious .plist files from the "LauncherPlugIns" and "LauncherDaemons" in the library (/library and ~/library).
- I've installed Malwarebytes on the Mac which successfully located and eliminated any files which might be related to these plug-ins.
- One of the two apps created a profile – which I eliminated from the System Preferences, whereas the other set itself to open whenever I logged in and I've impeded it to do so.
- I've rebooted the Macbook at least 15 times whilst doing all of this.

But, despite all these efforts, the plug-ins are still there and Safari's language won't change.

**My Question**

To rectify this, do I need to reinstall Safari and, if so, how? If not, what else do I have to do?

My last resort is to upgrade the Mac to Mojave, but I'm not sure that would resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**:

I just re-installed the OS. This caused Safari to display the "uninstall" option. After clicking it I was redirected to the "/users/shared" folder where I found the plug-ins and eliminated them. The language issue, however, remains.

**Question**

Is there a way, perhaps through the terminal, to force Safari to change its language (Italian in this specific case)?

**SOLVED**

After some more research I just found a solution. You may find it [here](https://it.ifixit.com/Risposte/Visualizza/524936/Different+languages+between+Safari+and+macOS.+HELP). I think it forces Safari to employ the language of your choice, not the one of the system.

Comment: The cleaner app probably removed all the language files.  You have to reinstall the os to get them back.

Comment: @TomGewecke No, the issue was present before I ran the scan, so I don't think that this might be what caused it in the first place. Also, Malwarebytes got rid of all the malicious files, but the extensions remained. So either Safari did not recognise that the files to run the extensions are not there anymore, or they're still somehow present in the system files. I'll consider reinstalling the OS, thank you!

Comment: Please post a self answer.. Also is malwarebytes the final call on such issues? you might want to read related questions on hacking etc on the site. Better not leave vulnerabilities.